# How to include drag and drop component into a-frame /web vr?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, aframe, webvr

I am using a-frame and trying to include the drag and drop feature-so I can drag and drop elements around. Nothing works and there is unfortunately not much online..I was looking at this:https://jesstelford.github.io/aframe-click-drag-component/
but nothing I try works.
Is anyone familiar with a-frame and can help?Thanks!!

browser/home.html:

```
  <scene scene-id="sceneId"></scene>
```

browser/js/app/directives/screne.html:

```
  <a-scene>
    <a-sphere click-drag position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
    <a-camera look-controls-enabled="false"></a-camera>
  </a-scene>
```

index.html

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-click-drag-component"></script>
<script>  registerAframeClickDragComponent(window.AFRAME); </script>
```

Comment: You've done this correctly according to the documentation. I would (1) make sure that your scripts are included before the `<a-scene>`, (2) check the JS console for any warnings, and if that's not working, (3) [file a bug](https://github.com/jesstelford/aframe-click-drag-component/issues/new) on the repository.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation seems like it needs updating.

Perhaps try calling `window.aframeDraggableComponent(window.AFRAME)` instead and file an issue to update the documentation.